# Preserving CSS style in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, css, excel

I have data in an Excel spreadsheet linked to a mysql database and on to the webpage through php. I am trying to style the lines with a CSS stylesheet but somewhere the data is changed meaning (I think) the browser ignores the CSS command.

Written in the spreadsheet is as follows:-

```
<p class="fixturedate"><strong>Friday May 17th 2013</strong></p>
```

Somewhere along the way, by the time it gets to the browser, this is being changed to:-

```
<p class=\"fixturedate\"><strong>Friday May 17th 2013</strong></p>
```

Any ideas why those two backslashes are being added? Is that the problem or is it just not going to work anyway?

Thanks

Comment: You are using echo, right?

Comment: is the data on the screen coming from mysql or excel?

Comment: Ideally, data should be going into the database using database specific escaping so that it's unescaped when it actually resides in the database.  Double escaping can cause the undesired slashes.

Comment: ....or escaping double quotes when your strings are enclosed in single quotes

Comment: OK got it - it was the double escaping causing the problem. Took the quote marks out and changed it to this :- 

<p class=fixturedate><strong>Friday May 17th 2013</strong></p>

and it worked.

Thanks.